# Volley shows null error when activity loads first time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I have view pager in my android activity and using NodeJs and MongoDb as a back-end service.When my activity starts first time it shows volley error null
and when i stop my app and start it again it loads images in the view pager and works fine.
Why it is not fetching data from the server when activity starts first time.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tab;

RequestQueue rq;
List<Model> list;
Adapter adapter;

String request_url = "https://example.com";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rq = CustomRequest.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getRequestQueue();

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tab = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    tab.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

    final ProgressDialog prg = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    prg.setMessage("Loading");
    prg.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, request_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            prg.dismiss();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArr  = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

                    Model model = new Model();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    model.setImage(jsonObject.getString("Image"));

                    list.add(model);

                }

                adapter = new Adapter((ArrayList<Model>) list, MainActivity.this);

                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            prg.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("place","Ajmer");

            return params;
        }
    };

    CustomRequest.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequetQueue(stringRequest);
 }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public Adapter(ArrayList<Model> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view == o;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert layoutInflater != null;
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);

    Model model =  list.get(position);

    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Glide.with(context).load(model.getImage()).into(imageView);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(view, 0);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

    container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
 }
}
```

Please someone let me know why I am getting this issue.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialized RequestQueue. if not please add following code before string request

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
```

After that call add queue.add after string request call

```
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

If the error still continues...
print response of volley whether its getting null or not.

Comment: Yeah i tried this,but still showing null when activity starts first time.I am using volley singleton pattern.